# AMPSCRIPT & HTML: How to capture response in HTML form before clicking the submit button?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html

I need a HTML form that is able to show a drop-down list based on the response selected from the set of radio buttons above it.

For example, my drop-down list ("Food Preference") has two values: "Vegetarian" and "Non-Vegetarian". I will require this drop-down list to only appear if the user selects "Attending" instead of "Not Attending". (Note: Attending & Not Attending is the radio button above the drop-down list).

This is my current codes. Currently it can only capture responses after the submit button is clicked:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 %%[ var @rsvpresponse, @foodpreference, @submit
     set @submit = requestparameter('Submit')
     set @rsvpresponse = requestparameter('rsvpresponse') 
 ]%%
<form action="%%=v(@deflandingpage)=%%" method="post">
  <br>
  <label>RSVP:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="rsvpresponse" value="Attending"> Attending
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="rsvpresponse" value="Not Attending"> Not Attending
  <br>
  <label> Food Preference </label>
  <select name="foodpreference">
  <option value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
  <option value="Non-Vegetarian">Non-Vegetarian</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input id="submitted" type="hidden" name="submitted" value="submitted" />
  <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1" />
  <input type ="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone knows how to modify my current script so that it can hide/show the dropdown list based on the user's rsvp selection above and before the submit button is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMPScript is a *server-side* scripting language, so it's evaluated *before* the page is displayed.

If you want this type of functionality, you'll need to go the client-side JavaScript with AJAX route (like with jQuery) and have a separate CloudPage that returns the options for your page to display.

That process is not specific to SFMC, except for how the secondary page retrieves the data -- that would need to be coded in AMPScript or SSJS.

[**Here's a simple, runnable example**](https://codepen.io/wvpv/pen/EwBaYq) of how the AJAX could work:

**HTML**:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">Load Cities</button>
<h4>Meetup Cities</h4>
<p class="cities"></p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

**Client-side JavaScript**:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {

  $('.cities').text('Loading...');

  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"https://api.meetup.com/2/cities",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      var $el0 = $('.cities');
      $el0.empty();
      $el0.append($("<select></select>").attr("class","cityList"));
      var $el = $('.cityList');
      $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", '').text('Select City'));
      $.each(data.results, function(value, key) {
        $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key.city).text(key.city + ", " + key.state));
      });   
    }
  });

});
```

To customize this, you'd replace the `https://api.meetup.com/2/cities` with the URL for your CloudPage.  The CloudPage should return the JSON object for the data you're wanting to display on your page dynamically.